# show/hide a layout on button press

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making a small interface with a vertical menu on the left and a free area on the right.
I want the user to hide or show the menu, thanks to the green button on the left.
When I click on this button, I want the menu to disappear if it is visible, or to appear if it is invisible

.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class SM(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SM, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Main(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def show_hide(self, menu):
        # ...
        pass

Builder.load_file("gui.kv")

class GUI(App):

    def build(self):
        return SM()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<SM>:
    Main:
        name: "main_screen"
        id: main_screen

<Main>:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Button: # <--- Show / Hide button
            size: (8,8)
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            text: "|"
            background_color: (0,1,0,1)
            on_press: root.show_hide(menu)

        BoxLayout: # <--- I want to show/hide this menu
            id: menu
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size: (120, 120)
            size_hint: (None, 1)

            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text:"( ** nothing ** )"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this case we can use the width and opacity of BoxLayout, we also create a Boolean property:

***.py**

```
class Main(Screen):
    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)
```

**.kv**

```
<Main>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        Button: # <--- Show / Hide button
            size: (8,8)
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            text: "|"
            background_color: (0,1,0,1)
            on_press: root.isShownMenu = not root.isShownMenu

        BoxLayout: # <--- I want to show/hide this menu
            id: menu
            orientation: 'vertical'
            width: 120 if root.isShownMenu else 0
            hight: 120
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            opacity: 1 if root.isShownMenu else 0

            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
```

Comment: Thank you ! how to make the green button in the foreground?